# c#.net connection string works with integrated security but not when specifying username and password

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication

I am new to sqlserver, I have a connection string as follows:

`< add name="test" connectionString="server=dbServer\SQLEXPRESS;database=test;integrated security=SSPI;" />`

and the site connects and works fine.

I created a user in SSMS 17.4, gave it a name

`< add name="test" connectionString="server=dbServer\SQLEXPRESS;database=test;User Id=dbUser; Password=letmein;" />`

the site fails saying "login failed for user 'dbUser'"

The user has following :

server roles: public, dbcreator

user mapping: 
    default schema: dbo
    database role memberships: db_owner, public

any idea why it fails on use of username/password?

Thanks

Comment: Check the SQL Server logs and post what the errors are in there, please.

Comment: 'keyword not supported userid' when I take out the space

Comment: Can you connect with that account in SSMS?

Comment: ah, in the log, 'server is configured for integrated authentication only'

Comment: And there is you answer. :) Change the server to mixed authentication.

Comment: thanks for the help, changing the configuration to mixed did the trick ..

Comment: @Larnu My connection strings for SQLExpress have several parameter names with white space and they work. Examples: Data Source, Initial Catalog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely causes include:

1) SQL instance is not configured to allow SQL auth

2) the login and/or password is wrong

3) the login does not have access their default database

Check the SQL Server error log as that will have more detailed info on the cause of the login failure. Those are not returned to the client for security reasons. The error log can be viewed from SSMS (Management-->SQL Server Logs) or via a text editor. The current log file is named "errorlog" (no extension) and located under the installation folder Log subdirectory by default.

Comment: Thanks, it was option 1:

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you would not have configured your SQL Server authentication mode.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHRv3.png)